# Bad Request with HTTP Get requests after update

Tags: xamarin, httpclient, bad-request

I have updated my Xamarin tools today from 4.1 to 4.2. Now my Android app gives me `Error 400: Bad Request`, when accessing my Web Servers.

The two servers I use are running IIS with SSL enabled.

Requests to one of the servers works OK. Requests to the other server I get 400: Bad Request, on Android 6. The same code works fine on iOS and Windows Phone. If I configure a proxy between the parties (e.g. Fiddler), everything works fine as well.

Does somebody experience the same problems or has a clue, whats going on on the Android device or Emulator?

I've tried experimenting with the different HTTP Client handlers in project properties, but none of them make a difference.

Here the relevant code:

```cs
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    Credentials = _credentials,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy,
})
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(_userAgent);
        client.Timeout = ExecutionTimeout;

        using (var msg = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancelTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After reviewing the Fiddler Output, I detected a minor difference in the sslv3 ClientHello handshake: Xamarin 4.1 used the server name in "Extensions: server_name"; Xamarin 4.2 uses the server name and port. Might this be the problem?

Comment: I've reformatted your question to be more concise and easier to read. Removed all the fluff... I've added syntax hilighting to your code as well. Also removed tags from title.

Comment: Also when using HttpClient, you should not use it in a using statement, even though it implements IDisposable. It should be considered a shared resource and static. Reuse it as much as you can to avoid having hanging open sockets to your web server. Also SSLv3 is vulnerable to Poodle, so you should consider using TLSv1.2 or higher instead.

Comment: Also what does the log on the server say when you make a request? Does your exception have a message or inner exception with more information? Does your output window show you more information on what goes wrong?

Comment: As for the server side, I'm not free to use anything I would like... Existing server with defined interfaces and protocols...
The IIS log does not contain my webrequest in case of error; either it is blocked by the firewall (it's a customer site) or its too early in the call chain for a log.
As for the client side, I do not get more Information; all I get is an HTML string with the mentioned error...

Comment: Could you try with ModernHttpClient's handler to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Your issue might be related to this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43411. Specifically that report is about an issue where Android drops spaces encoded as (%20) from URLs. A fix has been made for this bug, but the fix has not been released yet.

Comment: ModernHttpClient handler has fixed my reported problem. Even though preauthentication has not worked and I had to do it manually... As an added bonus, TLS 1.2 is now available too (if the server supports it as well)